# Ive got a term (get_term_by) but now I want to filter it by a category it is in?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

So I have my term, here is an example:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
```

This, for example, will return all 'Females' which is OK but now I only want to show females that are also in another category, e.g. Sports & Fitness. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) with Taxonomy Parameters. If you want posts that are in both categories, just add two conditions in tax_query (using an array for `terms` will get you posts that have at least one of those categories).
Note that you'll have to adapt the taxonomy to your needs. Instead of `slug`, you could also use `term_id`, `term_taxonomy_id` or `name` as the field to be searched.

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => "females"
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => "sport-fitness"
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```